# Compress Image faster than Bitmap.save C#

Tags: c#

I have a project that using split bitmap 10000x10000 pixel to 100x100 pixel, then I compress it to png. My code:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("file name");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            Bitmap cropped = bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(i*100, j*100, 100, 100), bitmap.PixelFormat);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            crop.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            Bitmap NewSmallBitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
            //work something with new bitmap
        }
    }
```

But it run very slowly - about 1ms for a loop, and 10 seconds for all loop. Do anyone have a solution with beter performance? Thanks

Comment: Apparently the loop iterations do not depend on each other, so this could be done in parallel.

Comment: If they are unrelated, you can run them concurrently.

Comment: Why creating `NewSmallBitmap` from `ms`? It should be a copy of `cropped`. You compress `cropped` in `ms` then you decompress it again in `NewSmallBitmap`. My suggestions: use threads (4 or 8) and try to measure the time taken by each operation (creating `cropped`, saving, creating `NewSmallBitmap`...). Also try to re-use `NewSmallBitmap`.

Comment: Have you profiled the code? I'd expect the problem is the `Bitmap.Clone`, not the `Bitmap.Save`. Find the bottle-neck, then find a way to get around it.

Comment: thanks :) seem my problemp has been solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look to use Tasks;

[TaskFactory.StartNew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to start a task, and you can call it several times. Each call returns a Task object; save that in a list or array.

Once you've started all your jobs, call [Task.WaitAll(Task[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) to wait for all the jobs to finish.

Comment: Thanks so much for help me, I'll try and report soon :)

Comment: No problem. Hope it's a useful approach.